# How to not comment in php

Tags: php, email

I'm not really good in PHP, so the solution propably easy, but what I'm trying to do is sent mail via php with link. Here's the code.

```
<?php
 $to="abc@gmail.com";
 $subject="This is subject";
 $message = "<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Click here</a></p>";
 $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; //this should set mail to html
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

The problem is the link in $message cause the rest of the line is marked as comment. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As the answer pointed out, the problem is that you tried to use double quotes inside other double quotes, which PHP can't make sense of. As far it's concerned, as soon as it found the next quote, it considered it as a closing quote: `$message = "<p><a href=" <-- for PHP, the string ends here`. This code should be raising a syntax error "Unexpected https".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put double commas inside another double commas, use simple comma or escape it.

Both are ok:

```
"<p><a href='https://www.youtube.com'>Click here</a></p>";

"<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com\">Click here</a></p>";
```

If u need, see the mail manual:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Bye!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use double quotations to quote text with double quotation(s).

One of the solutions is to change

```
"<p><a href="https://www.youtube.com">Click here</a></p>";
```

to

```
"<p><a href='https://www.youtube.com'>Click here</a></p>";
```